# How to prevent a paragraph, which is also a flex-item, from going full width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a bunch of flex-items in a container. The flex-direction is set to column. One of the elements has a little bit more text, so that its contents wraps into a new line. Now the element's width automatically becomes 100% of the width of the parent. How can I prevent this from happening?

To make it a bit clearer: The "green" should "stop" after the second "Twentyone".

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.long {
  /* ??? */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">One</div>
  <div class="child">Two</div>
  <div class="child long">Twentyone Twentyone Twentyone</div>
  <div class="child">Four</div>
  <div class="child">Five</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Basically NO. That's not the way wrapping works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<span>` element.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.child:nth-child(odd)>span {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.child:nth-child(even)>span {
  background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><span>One</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>Two</span></div>
  <div class="child long"><span>Twentyone Twentyone Twentyone</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>Four</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>Five</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use width to solve this problem

```css
        .long {
            width: min-content;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .parent {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 200px;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }

        .child:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: chartreuse;
        }

        .child:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: chocolate;
        }

        .long {
            width: min-content;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">One</div>
        <div class="child">Two</div>
        <div class="child long">Twentyone Twentyone Twentyone</div>
        <div class="child">Four</div>
        <div class="child">Five</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In this case, I get a line break after every word.

Comment: use span inside divs then